# Menu formatting is not retained

Tags: php, html, css

I wrote a menu in one menu.php and called it to another file. For reduction of code, I have only included what seem minimal/sufficient.

This is definition in style of main page.

```
#menu{position:absolute;top:100;left:260;height:40;width:490;}
```

This is where I call the menu.php

```
<div id="menu"><?php include("menu.php")?></div>
```

This is how I have defined menu.

```
  <ul id="menubar">
    <li><a href=#>HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>NEWS</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>RESOURCES</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>ABOUT US</a></li>
    </ul>
```

This is the style of menu in menu.php

```
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
body{font-size:120%;font-family:arial;background-color:#D4F1FA;padding:50px;}
ul#menubar{list-style-type:none;}
ul#menubar li{width:120px;text-align:center;position:relative;float:left;}
ul#menubar a{color:#DAECF2;text-decoration:none;display:block; width:120px;height:40px;line-height:40px;background-color:#153945}
ul#menubar li:hover>a{background-color:rgba(20,66,82,0.6);color:#C9E6F0}
```

The problem is The font size and color is not preserved in main file where it works in menu.php only. Any suggestions?

Comment: Though it's bad practice to write css in single line, disregard it.

Comment: are you css ruls in style tags or on css stylesheets?

Comment: there may be other css owerriting yours. inspect with element inspector in chrome or firebug in ff.

Comment: in style tags. the last style is in menu.php. the upper one is in index.php

Comment: you need to orgainse all the code better, will be easier to debug. Include them all in a stylesheet and you should be able to check it. Use firebug with firefox!

Comment: yes, it was overwritten. Thanks. all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include a php file that includes other files you have to write the full path of your css.

One more advice is to use tools like the chrome inspector to see if all your files loaded correctly.

so for example :

Don't do

```
<?php
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
?>
```

instead do

```
<?php
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/website/css/style.css">
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an unorthodox way of adding common content into file. You could make it more flexible by adding the html into a function and calling it at will.

```
function displayNav()
{

    echo "<ul id='menubar'>
             <li><a href=#>HOME</a></li>
             <li><a href=#>NEWS</a></li>
             <li><a href=#>RESOURCES</a></li>
             <li><a href=#>ABOUT US</a></li>
          </ul>";
}
```

You can add more functions for other common content as required.

Furthermore I would suggest moving your css into an external stylesheet; it will make it easier maintain and improve the readability of the markup pages.